# Grabbing attention of downvoters to edit

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

I have just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578692/python-algorithm-finding-index-in-an-array/38578723#38578723) to a question on Stack Overflow, and it seems like it was not what the asker meant to ask.

So I decided to edit my answer and provide a better solution and explanation. However, while I was editing the question, someone downvoted it (because it didn't fit to the question - something that is completely legitimate and understandable). However, I want that person to see that I edited the question and rethink of the downvote.

I have tagged the asker so he could see the edited answer, but is there a way to grab the attention of downvoters/commenters on my answer to the edit I made?

Comment: Question you've linked to is quite common interview question and should have plenty of answers on corresponding sites... Answering such questions that don't show any research effort generally comes with penalty of lost effort due to question removal by OP and of potential downvotes for answers as missing the point of question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have tagged the asker so he could see the edited answer, but is there a way to grab the attention of downvoters/commenters on my answer to the edit I made?

Since downvotes are anonymous you can't.

---

Don't make a drama about a single downvote here please.

If your answer is good, it will be upvoted over time.

---

Also the question is too broad and doesn't show any efforts. IMO it's a *"gimme teh codez pls"* question in disguise, and deserves to get closed (did vote now so) instead of being answered. I'm not very familiar with the behavior of the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) community though.

Comment: No, it's not about the single downvote. It's more like a theoretical question. I don't really care about the reputation or votes :P

Comment: @YotamSalmon Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: @YotamSalmon If you don't care, just don't answer such questions, but flag them as _off-topic_.

Comment: @YotamSalmon But THX pulling the _Meta Effect_ on this question.

Comment: I think the downvote is not necessary caused by the content of the answer, it can be just because it is appeared in a closed question

Comment: @amuse We closed the question afterwards, so no.

Comment: "Since downvotes are anonymous you can't." is unintelligent to say because they could be notified anonymously. What is this a kind of language?>> "Don't make a drama about a single downvote here please.". And with too much of this kind of people we can not be sure of this >> If your answer is good, it will be upvoted over time.